# When creating UiBinder in App Engine 1.7.4 and GWT 2.5.0 project and Eclipse Juno 4.2, the Design tab on Eclipse cannot render the panel

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-designer, google-eclipse-plugin

I created a simple UiBinder in Eclipse Juno 4.2 for a project created against App Engine 1.7.4 and GWT 2.5.0 and, the code looks like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

  <ui:image field='logo' src='Resources/logo_small.png' />

  <ui:style>
  @sprite .logo_small {
    margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
    gwt-image: 'logo';
    position: absolute;
  }
    .headerContainer {
      padding: 0 11px;
    }
    .welcomeDiv {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .tagLine {
      margin-left: 180px;
      padding-top: 22px;
      font-size: 1.8em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </ui:style>

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class='{style.headerContainer}'>
      <div class='{style.logo_small}' />
      <div>
        <div class="{style.welcomeDiv}">
          <b>Welcome back, foo@bar.com</b>
          -
          <g:Anchor href='javascript:;' ui:field='signOutLink'>Log Out</g:Anchor>
        </div>
        <div class='{style.tagLine}'>Your feeds are belong to us</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

But the design tab on Eclipse cannot render the panel and fails with the following error message -

```
was not able to show the GUI. 

Internal Error 

This could be caused by a bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/ProjectClassLoader
```

Comment: Also provide your environment information java version, os type version, hardware - 64 bit vs 32 bit etc....

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. My setup: Win7-64bit, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Juno Service Release 1,Build id: 20121004-1855. GWT Designer Core: 2.6.0.r37x201206111222, GWT Designer Editor: 2.6.0.r37x201206111227, GWT Designer GPE: 2.6.0.r37x201206111341

Comment: ==> java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

==> os details iMac running OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Seems like a bug to me since the GWT Designer works fine in Eclipse 3.7 (Juno)